# Please identify this flower

Tags: identification

Please identify this flower.

Characteristics: (I don't have much info about it)

- winter flowering species
- flowers gradually have started closing
- not much height

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its Gazania, but they are not winter flowering, though I suppose it depends on what part of the world you are in and how cold or hot your weather gets. In the UK, these are grown mostly as half hardy annuals during summer, meaning they will not tolerate any frost. There are a large number of varieties of this plant - some are listed here https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/search-results?query=gazania